# Ordered subsets summation

Tags: sequences-and-series, algorithms

Let $A$ and $B$ be two finite ordered sets where $A\subseteq B$. How do I count the number of consecutive and non-consecutive occurrences of $A$ in $B$?

For instance, I have nine occurrences of set
$A=\{0,1\}$ in the set $B=\{0,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,0,1\}$.

Comment: You mean finite sequences, right? As sets $A = \{0,1\}$, $B = \{0,1,2,3\}$ and there is nothing like "number of occurences" ... And: How do you want to count?

Comment: Are you looking for an algorithm?

Comment: @martini, I mean finite sequences. For instance, in $B\{0, 1, 2, 0, 1\}$, the ordered subset $A\{0,1\}$ appears twice. I'd like to count this.

Comment: Yes, @ArthurFischer. I'm looking for an algorithm.

Comment: Apparently you mean appearances only of **A** as consecutive entries in **B**, what might best be called consecutive subsequences.

Comment: If **A** is [0,0] and **B** is [0,0,0], how many appearances of **A** in **B** do you count?  That is, are appearances of **A** allowed to overlap?

Comment: Do you also want to count overlapping subsequences? For example, take $A=(0,1,0)$, $B=(0,1,0,1,0)$, should the result be $1$ (because the second $0$ is already "used up" by the first subsequence) or $2$ (because both at the first and the third item there starts a subsequence $(0,1,0)$)?

Comment: @hardmath, I want to count overlapping subsequences. I count 3 appearances of $A\{0,0\}$ in $B\{0,0,0\}$

Comment: @celtschk, I want to count overlapping subsequences. I count 5 appearances of $A\{0,1,0\}$ in $B\{0,1,0,1,0\}$.

Comment: @MarcosdaSilvaSampaio: Five? then which one of the two $1$'s in $0,1,0,1,0$ gets the most hits?

Comment: The proper term to use is that you want to count the number of occurences of a given _word_ $A$ as a _subsequence_ of another word $B$. The term "ordered set" is horribly ambiguous and certainly not appropriate here. Also I've often wondered why people would want to write something like $A\{0,1,0\}$ without the necessary equals sign after $A$.

Comment: @Marcos: Then how do you find only $3$ occurrences of `01` in `0012301201`? If you're counting non-consecutive subsequences, there would be $9$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm. It was my mistake. There are indeed 9 non-consecutive subsequences.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen. Thank you for the advise about $A=\{0,1,0\}$ instead of $A\{0,1,0\}$, once I'm a beginner studying math. Can I count also non-consecutive occurences of _word_ $A$ in _subsequence_ of another word $B$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following algorithm should do what you want (there are obvious optimizations which could be done):

```
define count(a, b):
  if a = []
    return 1
  else if b = []
    return 0
  else if first(a) = first(b)
    return count(rest(a), rest(b)) + count(a, rest(b))
  else
    return count(a, rest(b))
```

Here `first(s)` gives the first element of the sequence `s` (e.g. `first([1,2,2,1,3])` gives `1`), `rest(s)` gives the sequence with the first sequence removed (e.g. `rest([1,2,2,1,3])` gives `[2,2,1,3]`) and `[]` is the empty sequence. I've used the convention that the empty sequence occurs exactly once in any sequence (this simplified the algorithm).

For example, evaluating `count([0,1],[0,1,0,1])` gives in sequence

```
count([0,1],[0,1,0,1]) → count([1],[1,0,1]) + count([0,1],[1,0,1])
  count([1],[1,0,1]) → count([],[0,1]) + count([1], [0,1])
    count([],[0,1]) → 1
    count([1],[0,1]) → count([1],[1])
      count([1],[1]) → count([],[]) + count([1],[])
        count([],[]) → 1
        count([1],[]) → 0
        1 + 0 → 1
    1 + 1 → 2
  count([0,1],[1,0,1]) → count([0,1],[0,1])
    count([0,1],[0,1]) → count([1],[1]) + count([0,1],[1])
      count([1],[1]) → count([],[]) + count([1],[])
        count([],[]) → 1
        count([1],[]) → 0
        1 + 0 → 1
      count([0,1],[1]) → count([1],[])
        count([1],[]) → 0
      1 + 0 → 1
  2 + 1 → 3
```

So the algorithm correctly finds 3 different subsequences of `[0,1]` in `[0,1,0,1]`.

Comment: One of the obvious optimizations one has to apply is to memoize the results of `count`. Otherwise, the algorithm will produce the result by adding $1$s together, and since the result can be as large as $\binom{|B|}{|A|}$, that can be vey inefficient.

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is a [string searching algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm). (From an algorithmic point of view there's no relevant difference between sequences of numbers and sequences of characters).

Such algorithms come in a wide variety of choices, providing different tradeoffs between ease of implementation and speed of search.

The simplest is just to look at every position in $B$ sequentially and check whether a copy of $A$ begins there or not. Count the number of successes.

---

If, on the other hand, you want to count **non-contiguous** occurrences of $A$ in $B$, I suggest a dynamic-programming approach. For $1\le p\le|A|$ and $1\le q\le |B|$, let $N(p,q)$ be the number of district non-contiguous appearances of the first $p$ elements of $A$ within the first $q$ elements of $B$. Then you can compute $N(p,q)$ recursively
$$ N(p,q) = \begin{cases}
N(p,q-1)+N(p-1,q-1) & \text{if }A_p=B_q \\
N(p,q-1) & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$
plus some easy base cases that I'll let you imagine. If you fill in a table of $N(p,q)$s starting with low $q$s, the entire computation up to $N(|A|,|B|)$ takes time $O(|A|\times|B|)$.

Comment: It does not suffice to count the number of initial positions, as the counting requested is of subsequences, not of subwords.

Comment: @Marc: But the example in the question is clearly counting subwords, not subsequences.